# Run Java console app as a daemon (background)

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I've developed a Java console application that when start, open a console window and remain in foreground, i want to start that application in background .

Now i launch the application by this command line :

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour ?
It's enough change the command line parameter or i need to do some change on my code ?

Comment: your question is not clear.  Do you want to run as a Windows service?  Or do you want a console windows?  or both?

Comment: In what Operating System do you want to achieve this?

Comment: I'm on Windows and as a windows service could be a great solution . Is there a way to run a Java console application as a Windows ServicE ?

Comment: @aleroot, don't forget to accept an answer. 43% is really low.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is operating system dependent.

```
*nix: <your command> &
Windows: (opens a new console): start <your command>
Windows: (doesn't open a new console): start /b <your command>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are doing this in anything unix based then you can append & to the end which will spawn a new thread and keept it running in the background.

```
java -jar myapp.jar &
```

Comment: at least until you log out.  then it'll take the app with it.  Use `nohup` in front

Answer (score 4):

If you really just want it to run in the background, `java -jar myapp.jar &` will do the job. That way, it'll still die when the shell closes, but you can keep using your shell.

If you really want it run as a daemon, `nohup java -jar myapp.jar &` will do the job. That way, it'll continue to live when the shell closes.

If you want this to be reliable, you can prepare an init script or [upstart job definition](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html), or run it via Vixie `cron(8)` `@reboot` specifier to make it start at boot.

Comment: Just want to point that this would be for an Unix or a Linux machine and not for windows.

Answer (score 3):

Given that you're using Windows, you might consider [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/index.html).  I have used it on a project in the past.

Comment: Additionally you can do "javaw" instead of "java" which will run your program without a console window.  This is typically how a GUI based java program should be run. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html