# Controlling applications through Java

Tags: java, windows

I am looking for a way to mimic operating-system (Windows in specific) actions through Java. Preferably, the program should run in the background, but it is not a big deal if it does not. I got the background part covered thanks to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473071/run-java-console-app-as-a-daemon-background)** question. I was looking for the following specific features :

- Maximizing/Minimizing the currently active window. (Can be **any** window, not just the Java application window.)
- Closing the currently active window.
- Open installed programs, and system utilities like the calculator, paint, etc. (I figured out this one from **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243993/how-to-execute-command-line-exe-file-in-java)** question.)
- Shutdown/Restart (This one's done too, thanks to the question **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973643/shutdown-windows-with-java)**.)

### So, my actual **question** is:

Is it possible to **minimize/maximize** or **close** an application window from a java program? (in *Windows*)

***Example Scenario:***

Firstly the java program is started, and it runs either as a background process or as a window. Bottom-line is that it should be able to accept triggers like maybe a keyboard shortcut or microphone input to trigger the action. After that suppose a Chrome window is opened and is currently active. Now on pressing the pre-defined shortcut, the Chrome window will minimize/maximize or close.

If the answer to the question is yes, I could use some pointers to start with my application. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is like an OS shell programming interface.
In Java side you will define a few interfaces.
Another Java layer will detect which OS is used and will return an implementation of interface: Windows, Linux, Macosx.

Some functionality you  can have with simple bash command: in windows cmd, in linux .. to many. Eg shut down, launch MSPaint, Calculator.

Other functionality you can have it with windows API: you will need to write some JNI functions and call it. eg minimize, maximize. It is possible.

Edit: 
I see there is no accepted answer, although it is answered properly.
[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9bde4870-1599-4958-9ab4-902fa98ba53a/how-do-i-maximizeminimize-applications-programmatically-in-c) is a C# code which does what you need in Java.

Now you need to migrate this code to Java:

In your java class declare a function:

```
private native maximizeOrMinimizeWindowWithName(String windowName, boolean maximize);
```

Compile -it
use Javah.exe - it will generate the necesary .h files
Use a C editor, configure environment, use the generated .h file.

-include windows api headers
-load user32.dll
- do more stuf..

compile your C code to .dll

put the your.dll into your app PATH environment variable. ( windows has the . in path, linux not)

-text, bugfix,

- for more info you should see a basic JNI tutorials.

-upvote accept :)

Comment: @aksh1t you are welcome, once you will learn the basics with JNI, the next task will be relative easy, the first one is strange, hard and takes long :)

Answer (score 2):

This can be *initiated* from Java, but not actually implemented in Java. In other words, it will take a lot of platform-specfiic JNI library code to get it working.

Java will give you almost no benefit for your use case; you should avoid it altogether for this project.

Comment: Well, thanks for the input. I was thinking of making a java application for a college project which did system-actions like the mentioned ones after getting speech commands from the user, but it seems that java is not fit for this task. I would be better off manipulating applications like VLC which have a java wrapper. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). It's an system dedicated to `simulate user programmaticly`.

Using AH scripts you can easily access all open windows, installed programs and even control mouse and keyboard.