# How to open/run java / .jar minimized by using cmd console?

Tags: java, windows, swing, cmd, minimized

I found different possibilities to open *Windows* applications minimized from cmd.exe. Best related topics I found were:
[open program minimized via command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057448/open-program-minimized-via-command-prompt) and
[Run Java console app as a daemon (background)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473071/run-java-console-app-as-a-daemon-background)

What I couln'd get working is running a .jar from cmd in a minimized or background state. The window still pops up in front with, e.g. :

```
START /min javaw -jar App.jar &
```

or

```
START javaw -jar App.jar --new-window/min
```

or other variations of these cmd options.

I made a workaround by setting it up in the application itself with
[frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965336/how-to-minimize-a-jframe-window-from-java)

But does anyone know how to do this by cmd, or what could be the problem (Win7 x64)?